# Command 'apache2ctl -S' not working with exec() method

Tags: php, apache, exec

I'm trying to get a list of the virtual hosts of a server using a PHP script, but whenever I try to run the `apache2ctl -S` command using the exec() function it doesn't work.

The thing is, whenever I run that same command via terminal it works perfectly fine, but when I run it with exec it just prints **Action '-S' failed**.

Comment: php doesn't run with root privileges, never

Comment: @pierpy in CLI mode PHP has the permissions of the user who started it, in web-server mode it has the permissions of the web-server-user

Comment: @Pippo ok...  That's right, I know.  But PHP, without any user  modification (www-data in sudoers?) cannot run such commands. This is an explicit security measure...

Comment: In the terminal where it works perfectly fine, how does `php -r 'echo exec("apache2ctl -S"), "\n";'` work?

Comment: @pierpy Ok i agree, we are saying the same thing. However the permissions are those of the web server not of the PHP

Comment: @Pippo yes, I mean that. Runs with a some non-privileged user, maybe www-data. So, whatever is the user, trying sudo does not make sense for me! It's a security measure

Comment: Also, I think the question isn't a duplicate. That's another answer, wrong decision?

Answer (score 0):

**I corrected the answer because I wasn't sure I understood the context of the request.**

If the script runs on a web page, you should check that the web server has the right permissions: try `sudo -u www-data sh` (sudo to your apache/ngnix user) and then launch `apache2ctl -S`.You will see if the web server can launch that command with that parameter.

If the script runs in CLI mode, it will have the permissions of the user who started it. However you can try redirecting *stderr* to *stdout* to capture some lost output:

```
exec ('apache2ctl -S 2>&1', $output, $returnCode);
```